# Do ravens or crows cause damage to your garden?

Tags: container-gardening, birds

Yesterday evening I came home from work, and I saw what happened to my small garden:

[image]

[image]

At first, I was very angry. I mean, who could do that. So I asked around my neighbors if they noticed something. The neighbor from above said, he noticed 3 big crows in my garden. He guessed that what they did. I was not convinced. Because, ok, they could do that to the pots on the ground, but the pot I hang on the ladder, it's like someone took it out and threw on the ground.

And this morning, when I left for work, it happpend again. But this time, it happened only to the pot hanging on the ladder, and it fell on the boxes of Barbary Thuja, everything else was intact!

So now I am a little convinced, that's crows. If it's the crows, how can I prevent them?

Comment: I never saw anything like that, but corvids are strong, and smart. I've seen a pair of magpies that have figured out how to raid household waste bins - one holds the lid open while the other one gets inside the bin and throws anything "interesting" out onto the ground!

Comment: Could be a corvid, but their actions are generally purposeful. If they are lifting pots up, what's in them that they want? Might be worth a check for vine weevil or other root-eating larvae. As for preventing them, not a lot you can do. They are generally not problematic around the garden and are fascinating to watch. Perhaps set up a camera? It is likely they will soon get bored of your pots if there is nothing edible in them.

Comment: My balcony looked like that this morning - it was pretty windy overnight, and all the smaller pots had been blown over, with one or two plants completely out of their pots. Not sure that's the explanation for the one hanging on the fence though - but in the UK, overnight, it'd be foxes who'd do things like this, they like to play...

Answer (score 1):

Oh it could most definitely be crows or as some people in the comments have suggested it could also be magpies. Those are the crow-like birds which are white/blue with black heads (usually chubby).

You just need to catch the culprits in the act and scare the crap out of them; they won't come back.

Comment: Whether you can scare them depends how much human contact they are used to. I've seen magpies that will steal food from tables while people are sitting and eating!

Comment: ^ Yeah that's true. I supposed in my neck of the woods they don't have a lot of interaction with people.

Comment: Now I also think it is crow-like. it hasn't happened again, as George wrote above, they get bored ;-)